# How to raise additional error in Python and keep cause in stack trace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I wrote

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    raise ValueError(e, "Was unable to extract date from filename '%s'" % filename)
```

and now, when exception occurs inside `try` block, I loose information about it. I stack trace printed I see only line number with `raise` statement and no infomation about where actual `e` occured.

How to fix?

Comment: In python3, `raise` automatically retains the traceback.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to me that it didn't....

Comment: Here's what you get: `Exception: Test ....

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: ....

ValueError...`

Comment: Will check, but I needed line number of error cause line number inside try block and was unable to find it...

Comment: You might be able to salvage something with the `traceback` module.

Comment: Why? You said it already keep the trace?

Comment: Yes... but not the line number... :(

Comment: Hence, the question is actual...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `raise exc from another_exc`:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    raise ValueError("Was unable to extract date from filename '%s'" % filename) from e
```

Adding the `from e` will make sure there's two tracebacks connected by *The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception"*.